# How do I create an "iframe popup" when I hover over an <a> tag?

Tags: popup, hover

Here is the scenario: a User will see a list of company names, each wrapped in an  tag.  He is able to see dynamic information and as he hover over each name and then make a request.

So Given a list of companies, each wrapped in an  tag.

When the cursor hovers over an  tag

Then a "pop-up" appears that contains an -based, dynamic content.

Given the pop-up
When the User clicks on the "submit" button in the pop-up
Then the form (based on the framework" is submitted and ajax displays "request succesful"

So, because I am using a php-framework, I'd like to use iframe to contain the form.

Some challenges:

When the cursor is no longer hovering over the  tag, the hover disappears.  How do I keep it operating?

How do I make it appear in an  so I can have full form-submission and POST-ing dynamic values through the URL?

How do the "popup" disappear when the cursor is no longer on either the -tag or the pop-up itself?

Can I do it without loading a bunch of 's onto the page, because the list of companies could be long.

for an example:

http://browseusers.myspace.com/Browse/Browse.aspx hover over one of the link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[jQuery](http://jquery.com) with the [clueTip plugin](http://plugins.learningjquery.com/cluetip/demo/) is something I have used for this in the past.

Comment: Thanks, will this allow me to use it as an iframe?  Here's an example of what I want to use:

http://browseusers.myspace.com/Browse/Browse.aspx

Comment: I would ajax that content in rather than an iframe, if you have the option. I would imagine that because you can place html in the tooltip, you can include an iframe in the html.

There are also other tooltip plugins for jquery if that one doesnt meet your requirements, just google http://www.google.co.uk/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=jquery+tooltip+plugins

Comment: thanks, I'll probalby go with clueTip, why did you pick this versus other options?

Comment: Its the one I choose for a similar project a while ago.